# how to find fiscalquarter based on the start_date

Tags: mysql

How to find out the fiscal quarter of the day based on the start_date
suppose in my example
After writing this query my resultset will be like below

```
SELECT 
MIN(START_DATE) AS start_date, 
MONTH(MIN(start_date)) AS p
FROM 
xyz 
GROUP BY YEAR(START_DATE)

start_date p 
2001-01-01 1
2002-01-01 1
2003-01-01 1
2004-01-01 1
2005-01-01 1
2006-01-01 1
2007-01-01 1
2013-04-01 4
2018-02-01 2
2019-01-01 1
```

For each year the minimum  value of date and month is shown like above. From this result I should calculate the quarternumber of year i.e whichever the minimum start_date as displayed it has to become as quarter1.Suppose my minimum date for year 2013 is '2013-04-01' then Quarter has to show it as 1 (4,5,6-Q1,7,8,9-Q2,10-11-12-Q3,1,2,3-Q4) and if my minimum start date for the year 2018 is '2018-02-01' then the quarter has to show it like this(2,3,4-Q1,5,6,7-Q2,8,9,10-Q3,11,12,1-Q4)

Based on this above date now my output look like this

```
start_date  quarter
2001-01-01    1
2002-01-01    1
2003-01-01    1
2004-01-01    1
2005-01-01    1
2006-01-01    1
2007-01-01    1
2013-04-01    1
2018-02-01    1
2019-01-31    1
```

How to do in this query dynamically.. Please share the  query
Can anyone share the query and help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Prashant16 has a good solution, however what you are looking for doesn't make any accounting sense.  Fiscal Quarters are based on a companies official filing year for taxes.  Many small business use Jan 1 as basis, others have it scattered throughout the year.  However, from year to year, the fiscal quarter never changes -- hence Prashant's answer once you know what month is the basis for the company.

Comment: I agree with prashant answer.. But i dont know what month will be the starting month of the company.. So for this reason i am facing problem

Comment: Then it sounds like you are just fumbling with completely sample data, nothing specific and want to know how to compute it when you NEED to apply.  If so, just build a case construct like Prashant provided.  When you have the actual starting date of the company, change it then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  t.start_date ,
    ( CASE WHEN MONTH(t.start_date) IN ( 11, 12, 1 ) THEN 1
           WHEN MONTH(t.start_date) IN ( 2, 3, 4 ) THEN 2
           WHEN MONTH(t.start_date) IN ( 5, 6, 7 ) THEN 3
           ELSE 4
      END ) AS FiscalQuarter
FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS t
```

Comment: If we apply the above logic my output wont come correct why because for 2013 year i need the quarter1 instead of that it is showing 2 it is wrong in my scneario based on the above input and ouput has to show like below